# Static vector as a class objects container

Tags: c++

I've seen many questions and answers about this issue but still I can't solve my problem. How should I initialize a static vector? I'm also asking you for checking I use a default construct properly. I don't mean checking if it's working because I know that it does. I just wonder if it is an elegant implementation?

```
class Employee
{
private:
    static std::vector<Employee> employee;
    std::string name;
    int age;

    Employee::Employee()
    {
        std::string localName;
        int localAge;

        std::cout << "So... do you want to hire a new employee? Let's look at CVs " << std::endl;
        localName = "Marek"; //GenerateName();
        localAge = 21; //these function is not ready yet. it'd be just a rand()
        std::cout << "I've got one. What do u think about " << localName << " age " << localAge << "?" << std::endl;

        int decision;

        do
        {
            std::cout << "Do you want hire him [1] or not [2] ? " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> decision;

            switch (decision)
            {
            case 1:
                name = localName;
                age = localAge;
                decision = 0;
                break;

            case 2:
                employees.erase(employees.end());
                decision = 0;
                break;

            default:
                std::cout << "Incorrect option. Try again" << std::endl;
            }
        } while (decision != 0);
    }

public:
    static void Employ()
    {
        employees.push_back(Employee::Employee());
    }
};

int main()
{
    Employee::Employ();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: _"I've seen many questions and answers about this issue but still I can't solve my problem"_ Can you tell us first what about all those answers was unhelpful? It seems pointless to reproduce the common answers yet again if there was something specific that's different for your use case. For what it's worth, I can't see what that would be. Also, I don't really see _why_ you're using a `static` member here. Why not a nice `EmployeesCollection` class that you can instantiate in `main`?

Comment: I beg your pardon? I don't understand what do you mean by `EmployeesCollection` class. I've tried create `static void InstantiateVector();` but I didn't understand it completely. I've also found something about **boost** library but I've decided to solve the issue using standards tools

Comment: I'm asking you why you think you need a `static` member and, if you really do, why all the many answers you've already read did not help you. No need to "beg my pardon" thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code didn't work when I ran it.  In addition to adding includes and fixing some typos, I had to add this line:

```
std::vector<Employee> Employee::employee;
```

However, I don't think this is the best solution.  For sweet clarity's sake, an Employee shouldn't contain a vector of Employees, but should be, well, an employee.  If you want a vector of employees, you can declare one in main (or elsewhere).  If you want your vector of employees to have some added features like the interactive employee-adding function you wrote, you can do it like this:

```
class EmployeeForce: public std::vector<Employee>
{
   void interactivelyAddEmployee ();
   ...
};

...
EmployeeForce myStaff;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've written on another forum and I've got the same answer like you. Take a look how my code looks now. I'd be grateful if you'll review it for me. Do I do it properly now?

Comment: OK, I got it.  That is basically the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed entire the concept. The problem was that I unnecessary wanted to put inside the class the container of objects (in this case: std::vector). I know now that class should only contain informations about the single object; it shouldn't know about anything about others one.

```
class Employee
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int age;

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<Employee>& v)
{
    out << "[";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        out << "Name: " << v[i].name << " age: " << v[i].age;
        if (i != v.size() - 1)
            out << ", ";
    }
    out << "]";

    return out;
}

Employee generate_random_employee(Employee obj)
{
    obj.name = "Marek"; //GenerateName();
    obj.age = 21; //these function is not ready yet. it'd be just a rand()

    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    int decision;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Employee> employees;
    Employee some_new_employee;

    std::cout << "Welcome mrs. manager. What do you want to do today, sir?" << std::endl << std::endl;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Hire sombody [1], Fire somebody [2], Exit [0] " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> decision;

        switch (decision)
        {
        case 1:
            some_new_employee = generate_random_employee(some_new_employee);

            if (should_i_employ(some_new_employee))
            {
                employees.push_back(some_new_employee);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            std::cout << "Who do you want to fire?" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> name;

            if (is_the_employee_exist(employees, name))
            {
                if (are_u_sure())
                {

                }
            }
            else
                std::cout << "" << std::endl;

            break;

        case 3:
            std::cout << employees << std::endl;
            break;

        case 0:
            std::cout << "Good bye, sir" << std::endl;
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "There is not these option. Try again " << std::endl;
        }

    } while (decision != 0);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question (your own), it is only code without any explanation. A *good* answer should indicate what was done to fix the problem.